# why does python decorator, is throwing recursion error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

```
def greet_decorator(print_name_function): # Decorating a function
        def wrapper():
            #function as an object
            hello_name()
            print('\tMr. Sunshine')
            
            
        return wrapper
    #my_obj = greet_decorator(hello_name)
    #my_obj()
```

when I'm using Decorator Recursion Error is occurring can anyone explain me this concept to me in detail

```
@greet_decorator
def hello_name():
    print('Hello!')
hello_name()
```

Comment: The `greet_decorator` decorator replaces `hello_name` with the function `wrapper`. `wrapper` tries to call `hello_name`, which is itself. That is infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of the `greet_decorator` decorator replaces `hello_name` with the function `wrapper`. `wrapper` tries to call `hello_name`, which is itself. That is infinite recursion.

Perhaps you meant to call the original (undecorated) function, which is passed in as the argument `print_name_function`.

```
def greet_decorator(print_name_function):
    def wrapper():
        print_name_function()
        print('\tMr. Sunshine')
    return wrapper

@greet_decorator
def hello_name():
    print('Hello!')

hello_name()
```